# How to set a program to be in the foreground in the xinitrc?

Tags: x11

I have a full screen OpenGL program which I wrote (see display.cpp in https://github.com/ehsteve/SAAS for the full source code) which I'd like to open automatically when X11 starts up. I've edited my xinitrc to start it up like so

```
   /path/to/binary/display &
   xterm -geometry 80x66+0+0 -name login &
   exec twm
```

The problem is that my program opens and is then covered up by the xterm. I'd like my program to be foregrounded and the xterm in the background so that when I quit I am presented by the xterm. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You can make your program sort of always-on-top by having it process `MapNotify` with `SubstructureNotifyMask` on the root window, and raise its own window whenever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Ugly shell tricks

This might work:

```
(sleep 3; /path/to/binary/display) &
```

It's sort of a hack, but it delays the program from starting right away. xterm will presumably have opened after 3 seconds, and then your other program will open on top. You can change the argument to `sleep` to whatever seems to work best.

### Window manager hints

The other option would be to edit the source code of the display program to ask the window manager to always place it on top. Some window managers let you set that sort of thing in an options menu, but probably not twm.

### Uglier shell tricks

Another idea would be to do something with `xwininfo`, if you want the `sleep` time to be more accurate. I haven't tried this one yet.

If you know what the xterm window will be named when it appears, and no other window will have that name, you could do something like this:

```
xterm &
(while ! xwininfo -name xterm >/dev/null 2>&1; do sleep .2; done; exec /path/to/binary/display) &
```

That waits until the xterm has appeared, rather than just hoping that 3 seconds is about right.

I'm not sure whether you should have the `exec` in `(sleep 3; exec /path/to/binary/display) &`. Without it, there may be a bash process running needlessly until `display` exits.

Comment: I just tested this and it does work. Feels like a bit of a kludge but whatever works!

Comment: If it's okay with you I'd like to wait to see if there are any other answers before awarding the bounty.

Comment: @ehsteve That's fine. If someone can come up with a more elegant solution, I'd be interested to see it. My .xinitrc file is sort of ugly. Glad it worked though.

Comment: btw you have a typo "Window Manger hints". I think we waited long enough. Thanks again for your answer!

Comment: @ehsteve Thanks. Maybe all the Christmas decorations at stores are making me think of mangers...